# Close Angular modal from different controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-ui

I am new to Angular (I have to edit a project after my former colleague).

I have defined FormController and ModalController.
ModalController is defined like this:

```
angular.module('app', [...]).controller('ModalController', ['part', class {
    constructor(part) {
       this.part = part;
    }
}]);
```

And in FormController I have following code to open modal:

```
openModal(template, part) {
    this.$uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: template + '.html',
        controller: 'ModalController',
        controllerAs: 'ModalCtrl',
        resolve: {
            part: () => {
                return something;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My problem is to close modal (after click on button in view).

Comment: You can do that by jquery: 
     
    $("#modalName").modal('hide');

Comment: @Jenny most Angularjs developers try to avoid suggesting using jQuery when answering Angularjs questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to inject the dependency `$uibModalInstance` into the Modal's controller.

Then you can use either `$dismiss` or `$close` as shown in this example taken from [UI Bootstrap Docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/):

```
  $ctrl.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close($ctrl.selected.item);
  };

  $ctrl.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
```

Since you controller is instantiated as `part` you would use that and presuming you don't need to pass a result or reason you can remove those params from the methods too:

```
  part.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close();
  };

  part.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
  };
```

Also a note if you see something prefixed `$uib` being used that means it is a part of the [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) component, hopefully that knowledge should help with the search for any more info you need in the future.

Comment: And how do I pass modal instance into ModalController?

Comment: You can pass it into you controller declaration this way `angular.module('app', [...]).controller('ModalController', ['part', '$uibModalInstance', class {
    constructor(part, $uibModalInstance)`

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the modal instance into the controller this way:

```
angular.module('app', [...]).controller('ModalController', ['part', '$uibModalInstance', class {
    constructor(part, $uibModalInstance) {
       this.part = part;
    }
}]);
```

And as Callum has put it, use the `dismiss()` and `close()` functions of `$uibModalInstance` to close the modal instance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject the instance of uib-modal into the controller of modal which contain the close method. which you can use to close the modal.

```
openModal(template, part) {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: template + '.html',
        controller: 'ModalController',
        controllerAs: 'ModalCtrl',
        resolve: {
            part: () => {
                return something;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Inject modalInstance into the modal controller and then you can use

```
modalInstance .close()
```

method to close the modal.